# What happens if a site package is updated beyond the version I specified in a virtualenv with pip?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Assume I have a virtualenv installation that does *not* use `--no-site-packages`. I run `bin/pip install somepackage==1.0.0`, but it's already present in my `site-packages` so it's not installed. Later, the copy installed `site-packages` is updated to `somepackage==2.0.0`.

What will happen in my virtualenv? Will it use the version 2, or download version 1 for itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If none of the packages that are importing `somepackage` use the `setuptools` API, then it works as described above.  If any packages in your virtualenv use `setuptools` (or `Distribute`) to specify specific version requirements for `somepackage`, `setuptools` will search for a version of `somepackage` that meets the requirements.  If it can't find a suitable installed version at install time, it will search externally and attempt to install it.  If it can't find one at runtime, the program fails with an exception.

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    version = "0.1",
    scripts = ['say_hello.py'],
    install_requires = ['somepackage == 1.0.0'],
)
```

For example, if `somepackage 1.0.0` was already installed in the system site-packages, everything is fine.  If you then update the system site-packages to `somepackage 2.0.0` with `pip`, which uninstalls the old version, the script will fail at runtime with:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: somepackage==1.0.0
```

If you installed both versions of `somepackage` with `easy_install` instead of `pip`, things would normally be different.  By default, `easy_install` does not uninstall packages and it supports multiple versions of packages (multi-version eggs).  So both versions of `somepackage` would be available in the system site-packages and the script would not fail.

`setuptools` (and the `Distribute` clone of it) has to jump through many hoops to make the multiple version support work reasonably.  Many developers frown on all that extra complexity and argue that it is easier and more transparent to support multiple versions of packages with separate `virutalenv`'s and, for that, the simpler model of `pip` is more appropriate.  (In fairness to `setuptools`, `virtualenv` came along later.)

Answer (score 1):

Only the first package/module found in `sys.path` with the given name will be used. If your venv is earlier than the system directory then your venv will be used.

Comment: I believe in my scenario nothing would be installed into the virtualenv because a suitable installation would already be found in `site-packages`.

Comment: If nothing is installed then it becomes the trivial case of nothing being in your venv to override the system directory in the first place.

Comment: So virtualenv's Python will use the updated version in site-packages, and pip won't do anything to ensure that the original specified version is still used, so it is necessary to use `--no-site-packages` to ensure a specific version, correct?

Comment: Or you need to force installation into the venv regardless of the presence of the package in the system directory.